# Struggling to set width using flex-grow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've set: `flex-grow: 3;` onto my `section.form-area` but it's being ignored. Rather the width seems to be determined by the sections siblings (section.image) image and text width.

Can anyone advise? Ideally I want this section to be three times bigger than the other (`section.image`).

https://jsfiddle.net/pecm23ot/2/

Omitting any redundant text my CSS & HTML is:

```
:root {
  --footer: 20px;
  --fullHeight: calc(100vh -var(--footer));
}

html {
  font-size: var(--font-size);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: var(--fullHeight);
  font-family: var(--font-family);
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

section.image {
  display: flex;
}

.logo-area {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

section.form-area {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 3;
}

.text-area {
  margin: 40px 0 20px 20px;
}

.form {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 20px 0 10px 20px;
}

.button-area {
  margin: 10px 0 10px 20px;
}

button {
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

footer {
  padding: 8px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: auto;
}

<body>
<main>
    <section class="image">     
        <div class="logo-area">
        </div>   
    </section>
    <section class="form-area">
        <div class="text-area">
        </div> 
    <div class="form">
    </div>
<div class="button-area">
</div>   
</section>
</main>
<footer>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `flex-grow` is NOT the same as `width`.

Comment: *"Rather the width seems to be determined by the sections siblings (section.image) image and text width."* That's how it's supposed to work. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow

Comment: If I look at something like: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flex-grow I can see a section expanding? No matter the width of the page the section.image remains fixed at a small size? Am I missing something @Paulie_D

Comment: Did you note that all the children have a flex-grow value. That is not the case in your code.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference if I add: flex-grow: 1; to the other section? https://jsfiddle.net/1gcd7yso/